# Sequelize Model Setter set from another property

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to create a sequelize model where one of the properties gets its value set from a couple other properties but i have not have any luck after few hours of researching around and trying different things.

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    userName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    fullName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        getterMethods: {
            fullName() {
                return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
            }
        },
        setterMethods: {
            fullName(value) {
                const names = value.split(' ');
                this.setDataValue('firstName', names.slice(0, -1).join(' '));
                this.setDataValue('lastName', names.slice(0, -1).join(' '));
            }
        }
    },
    userType: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    directPhone: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },


})
}
```

I basically have this user model that I want the "fullname" property to be a concatenation of the firstName and lastName property.

The above code is the latest version I have after looking around but certainly does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you have a problem with how you defining your setters and getters [ref](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#getters--amp--setters)

Comment: yes, I understand I have a problem. I was trying many things and this was just one of the failed attempts. If you could help me understand that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('Users', {
    id: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER, allowNull: false, autoIncrement: true, primaryKey: true },
    userName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    fullName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        get: function() {
            return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName
        },
        set: function(value) {
            const names = value.split(' ');
            this.setDataValue('firstName', names[0]);
            this.setDataValue('lastName', names[1]);
        }
    },
    userType: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    directPhone: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },


})
}
```

Comment: so sorry but will need to try this in my work computer tomorrow but thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: this does not seem to work still. I believe it's because the getter/setter functions take precedence so those properties are actually undefined at the point when the getter/setter functions execute. :s